# mongodb / mongoose create index based on array operator $size?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, indexing, mongoose, operator-keyword

Is it possible to create a partial index on a collection using the array operator $size?  For example, if I had a blogPost schema with an array field `comments:[type:String]`, could I index the collection based on the number of comments per blogPost

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can index by array length. However you can modify your schema to have a comment count. You can then add an index on that field and use atomic update operations to add comments while incrementing the comment count:

```
BlogPost.update(
    { 
        _id: "123" 
    },
    {
        $push: {
            comments: "new comment"
        },
        $inc: {
            commentCount: 1
        }
    }, callback);
```

Just add an index on `commentCount` and it should solve your problem.